# jQuery: How to toggle H1 tags at different time intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to toggle two `h1` tags. The first one needs to be displayed for `3 seconds` on the screen, and the second needs to be displayed for `8 seconds` on the screen.

I need a jQuery solution.

Comment: what mean toggle h1? you want hide after 3 seconds?

Comment: Yes. And then show the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

**HTML**

```
<h1> This is first H1 </h1>
<h1> This is Second H1 </h1>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initially hide second h1
    $("h1:nth-child(2)").hide();

    function show_second_h1(){
        $("h1:nth-child(1)").hide();
        $("h1:nth-child(2)").show();
        setTimeout(show_first_h1,8000);
    }


    function show_first_h1(){
        $("h1:nth-child(1)").show();
        $("h1:nth-child(2)").hide();
        setTimeout(show_second_h1,3000);
    }

    setTimeout(show_second_h1,3000);
});
</script>
```

it will call `show_first_h1()` and `show_second_h1()` at given time-interval one by one to show respective `H1` tag.

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCT8a/1/)

**EDIT:**

If you have control over HTML and can set `id` for H1 then following is simplified code. 
**HTML**

```
<h1 id="first"> This is first H1 </h1>
<h1 id="second"> This is Second H1 </h1>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //initially hide second h1
    $("#second").hide();

    function show_second_h1(){
        $("#first").hide();
        $("#second").show();
        setTimeout(show_first_h1,8000);
    }


    function show_first_h1(){
        $("#first").show();
        $("#second").hide();
        setTimeout(show_second_h1,3000);
    }

    setTimeout(show_second_h1,3000);
});
</script>
```

simplified demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCT8a/2/)

Answer (score 0):

[Click for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qnw3/1/)

### HTMl

```
   <h1 id="h1">

        heading 1
    </h1>
    <h1 id="h2">
            heading 2
    </h1>
```

### Jquery

```
function ToggleI() {
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#h1').toggle();
}, 3000);
    setTimeout(function(){
  $('#h2').toggle();
}, 8000);
}
window.setInterval(ToggleI, 1000);
```

Check this out